# Angular - select - filter more than one values

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown in Angular. And I want to restrict some values.
I tried with filter as in the below Plunkr.

It works for only one id at a time. But if I want to display two records for example 1 and 2. How to do it ?

**Plunkr:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/CumFFs9dMMb4krosKKZC?p=preview

**Javascript**

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
 angular.module('ngrepeatSelect', [])
   .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

     $scope.filterCriteria ;

     $scope.data = {
       repeatSelect: null,
       availableOptions: [
         {id: '1', name: 'Option A'},
         {id: '2', name: 'Option B'},
         {id: '3', name: 'Option C'}
       ],
     };
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

**HMTL**

```
<body ng-app="ngrepeatSelect">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <form name="myForm">

    Filter <input type="text" ng-model="filterCriteria"> <br><br>

    <label for="repeatSelect"> Repeat select: </label>
    <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="data.repeatSelect">
      <option ng-repeat="option in data.availableOptions | filter : filterCriteria" value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <hr>
  <tt>repeatSelect = {{data.repeatSelect}}</tt><br/>
</div>
</body>
```

**Update:-**

I am trying to achieve to reduce some of the available drop down values from the original big list to a small list. ( Side note : I just need a single select and not multi-select feature.)

Comment: Your Plunkr does not seem to work

Comment: I think you need to set your <select> to multiple and then pass the selection as your filter and in your controller build the filter accordingly..

Comment: @BobDoleForPresident Yes it hangs before now seems to be fine.

Comment: @Jay Still hanging for me

Comment: It depends how you want to restrict the values. If you just want to limit the number of options to display, you can use `limitTo`.  If you really want to use filter function, please explain how restrict you want to. And are you  trying to filter the value based on random input from users?

Comment: @Thierry Thanks I am not looking for multi select feature. Just trying to reduce the available drop down list values according to some input.

Comment: Is the input randomly or fixed?

Comment: @Jay Still hanging for me too :)

Comment: @BobDoleForPresident  Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/ieCqMiUeJ55rqqHJhuzN?p=preview

Comment: @ShaohaoLin Thanks, In this example if I want to select both 1 and 2 how to do that ? It only works if I enter either 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: I am a little confused  , you said not multiselect above there  ? What are we looking for actually ?

Comment: I'm with @Katmanco. Kinda confused.

Comment: @Jay If I was to put 1 in the filter box what exactly would you like to see?

Comment: First of all, the data that presented is very limited. There is no so much can do using filter function. However, check the new link, when you input 1, it gives you only 2 options. http://plnkr.co/edit/NWutcmUrFXWQoyWKaCxD?p=preview

Comment: @ShaohaoLin Thanks for the link. But I did not mean that way:-(  Each drop down values would be unqiue.  I have two dynamic drop downs. And based on first drop down selection I just want to reduce the number of items displayed on the second drop down. All drop down are NOT multiselect. It is just the values displayed changes. Both dropdown have fixed set of values. But the number of items reduces based on other drop down selection. Hope I explained better.

Comment: @ShaohaoLin Yes something like that.

Comment: Then you need customer filter.